# How to recognize the color of a poker card using OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, shapes

I am currently willing to implement an iOS app that uses OCR to compute poker stats (you put your cards on a table, then take a picture with your iPhone camera and then magic happens). I know that OpenCV for iOS is the way to go but I don't find any code sample to also recognize the color (spade, heart, club, diamond) of the cards. How can I do it?

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing it. Start with [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html), for example. Hint: if you put your cards on the table (showing them to other players), you can have the better statistics in the world, but you are unlikely to win :D

Comment: Thank you. Actually someone that already did the same kind of stuff just mailed me to use tesseract (a google project) to recognize the card color symbols as a font. I will investigate that way. But i'm still intereseted by a full highlight of how to proceed.

Comment: Probably he's bluffing... :D You don't need to perform OCR to get the suit of a card, etc... Most likely you'll be able to read the number (with some preprocessing, though)

Comment: read the number is the easy part I think. But for the suit it's more complex. How would you do as you seem to know the subject?

Comment: template matching or feature matching. Have a look on google and SO, there are already a number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of "understanding" the picture and each way has it's own pros and cons. template matching will not be a good idea since the cards are different and simply a very round heart and somewhat sharp and pointy heart would be the same but for template matching it would be a totally different "heart" , If you are sure that the user is going to input 2 cards than you would rather crop the cards and separate them. This can be done with simply snap color detection ( use canny edge detector to detect edges). Then you want to search for all the suits and find which one got the best result. You can use the "BOW" (bag of words approach) (google it a little bit) it's about building a visual vocabulary and simply with the frequency of visual words you must be able to tell which is which.
   Generally nothing can give you a 100% guarantee but with BOW you can pull out some interesting results.